# Difficulty with relationships creation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Hello friends,

I have a difficulty creating relationships in Power BI. I thought I created them properly, but when I create visualizations i clearly understand smth is wrong.

I will greatly appreciate if someone may give me an idea where I am wrong.

Comment: Is hard to say what is not ok, if we dont know what output do you expected; Which of this table are your Facts table and which are dim ? Currently its looks like Locations/Dimensions is your Facts (based on model relationship)

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing in relationships of PowerBI is that inactive relationships (the dotted line) has no effect on measures and calculation. So they can be removed (however,they can be used in measures with USERELATIONSHIP in DAX thus maintaining them is beneficiary).

Avoid many-many relationship that cause confusion. In your case, I believe the "last ship date" table relation with both 'Locations/Dimensions' and 'Move Type' has brought confusion.